# compare 20% of a column's number with a known value in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database structre :

```html
id  |  order | amount

  1     shoe     20000
  2     cap      10000
  3     shirt    5000
```

Now, i want an sql query that calculates 20% of each amount, compares it with 4000 (shoe in this case)
and returns any of such record that meets such comparison. currently, here is what i have:

```html
SELECT id, order, amount
    INTO @prod_id, @order_name, @order_amount,
    FROM sales_table WHERE ((amount * 20) / 100) = 4000;
    
    IF @prod_id IS NOT NULL OR @prod_id != '' THEN
        PRINT 'kooooool';
    END IF;
```

Honestly, I am not sure if that statement is correct, eventhough i expect record 1 (shoe) 
to be returned in my query. and no response seem to be coming from my output. How can i achieve this ?
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lot easier than what you are doing. You can change the `>=` by `=` or whatever you need.

```
SELECT id, order, amount
FROM sales_table 
WHERE ((amount * 0.2) >= 4000;
```

Comment: @natcho thanks. sorry for my delay before accepting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 issues with your code that I can see:

1. there is no print statement in mysql
2. you can't have an if statement outside of a stored programme in mysql
3. the select into without a limit 1 probably results in an error

I would simply do a select instead o this convoluted solution:

```
SELECT id, order, amount
FROM sales_table WHERE amount = 4000 * 5;
```

I changed the where criteria so it may be able to use an index on the amount column, if there is any.

Comment: i know, ther'es no print statement in mysql. just put it there for explanation purpose. but your solution seems to confuse me the more. I wanted to understand the nitty gritty

Comment: What nitty gritty did you want to understand?

Comment: i mean, why multiply 4000 by 5 again? where is the 20% calculation there ?

Comment: Erm, elementary school math. 20% is one fifth of a value. So, if you expect 20% of sg to be 4000, then 4000*5 is the original value...

Comment: thanks ! but your solution will compare original amount (20000) with 4000 * 5 (WHERE amount = 4000 * 5). but i need to compare 20% of any original amount with 4000

Comment: In your question you compare 20% of the amount with 4000, not with 4000*5. I just played around with the numbers, but the result is the same.